# Rails show validate errors on create self class custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, oop, validation

I have class filter_report.rb

```
class FilterReport
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :company_id

  validates :company_id, presence: true

  def initialize(options = {})
    options.each {
      |k,v|
      self.send( "#{k.to_s}=".intern, v)
    }
  end
```

How to call the FilterReport class to show my validate

I want to showw

```
report = FilterReport.new
report.company_id = ""
report.valid? => false
report.save => undefined save
```

I want to know about the message of validation presence.

> "company can't blank"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `ActiveModel::Validations`, you'll find `errors`:

> Returns the `Errors` object that holds all information about attribute error messages.

`Errors` implements a whole slew of different methods, but you probably want `#[]`:

```
report.errors[:company_id] # => "company can't be blank"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the errors by using `report.errors` . If you want the error messages, then you can use `report.errors.full_messages`

To customize the error message, you can write

```
validates :company_id, presence: {:message => "Company can't blank"}
```

Now you get the error by using `report.errors[:company_id][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Set the validation message in Model as

```
validates :company_id, presence: {:message => "company can't blank"}
```

You can get the error messages in

```
 report.errors.messages[:company_id].first.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

For it, you should pass message to validation if it is presence. The code will be like this

```
validates :company_id, presence: {:message => "Company can't blank"}
```

To check message

```
report.errors[:company_id]
```